# Code compiles in Eclipse but same code doesn't compile in new Android Studio

Tags: java, android, incompatibility, android-studio

Code works flawlessly in Eclipse.  Decided today I would give `Android Studio` a shot today.  Did all the necessary prerequisites and imported my code according to the Android guide.  Now my same code that was working in Eclipse is not compiling in Studio.

Here is an example of an error that appears in most of my activities:

SwarmConnect doc:  [HERE](http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/setup)

```
import com.swarmconnect.SwarmActivity;

public class MainMenu extends SwarmActivity {

    ImageView image;
    Button startBtn, highscoresBtn, aboutBtn, comingsoonBtn, biblestudyBtn;
    TextView title, subtitle;

    public static final String notice = "notice";

    Context c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

        c = this;  // Incompatible types.  Required: android.content.Context.  Found: matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.MainMenu
```

Is this happening to anyone else such as old code that is was working in Eclipse not working in the new Android Studio?

**EDIT**

Added a link to SwarmConnect doc showing that SwarmActivity is the way to extend a class to get their library to work.  Also added the `SwarmActivity` import to the code.

Comment: Are you *sure* SwarmActivity is a subclass of Activity? Maybe your definition of SwarmActivity got messed up somehow.

Comment: You should read [Migrating from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html), and config on Project structure, check if SDK add?

Comment: @EdwardFalk - edited my post with more info on SwarmActivity.

Comment: @Siddharth - the error is already commented into the last line of my code posted.

Comment: @CrossleSong - I read that document and completed all steps prior to my opening post.

Comment: Reformatted your question to make the error more prominent. I can bet you dont have your library in libs folder, AND/OR have not refreshed and done a clean build.

Comment: Rolled back edit to original author's version, because **unlike the 3rd-party edit, it indicates the line with which the error message is associated**

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you're probably using the Eclipse compiler (ecj). Android Studio uses Gradle, which uses the Java command-line compiler (javac). It's not a problem with Android Studio, but a difference between how the two compilers handle generics.